# Ion-Input does not looses focus when clicked outside

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I am having an ion-input. When i run in browser It works fine.

Problem is in Windows appx build. When we type some number in the input field.
And then click else where outside the input field.

Then if i press backspace it erases the number in the ion-input field.
It should not erase.

It works fine in browser.

Please help me.